# In app purchase does not work when live

Tags: iphone

I have an app in the app store that I have added an in app purchase for, I fully tested it in the sandbox environment and all worked fine. I have had the app update and the in app purchase approved by apple and according to iTunes connect all has gone live. The app updates just fine but then in app purchase simply doesn't work!! No products are returned! Anyone else have this problem? Surely if it worked in the sandbox and apple has approved it, there should be no issues!?

Answer (score 24):

It's all working just fine now! I didn't do anything it just seems to have taken about 36 hours for the in app purchase product to propagate through apples servers! :)

Comment: thanks for posting this.I just released my application and facing the same problem. Waiting for the in apps to be available shortly.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for posting this. I was having a mild heart attack after my first app with in-app purchases went live, but it started working after about 2 hours in my case. This SO questions stopped me from freaking out.

Comment: Mine are still in that flux period... fingers crossed.

Comment: I am waiting since last 72 hours. still not outcome

Comment: @ShourobDatta are you still waiting.? :p

Answer (score 4):

We just went live about an hour ago with the EXACT same issue.  Everything worked during testing and even when Apple reviewed the application.  I even verified they completed test purchases via analytics.  But when users in the app store download the update, try to buy the feature it just fails.

My only guess is our store data has propagated to their live servers?  The apps are still using the sandbox environment?

Comment: It's nice to know I'm not alone! So I guess we just have to wait to see if the data propagates? Please let me know how you get on and if your situation changes and I will do likewise!

Comment: My app's in-app purchases finally started working just under 24 hours after the app went live.  It was definitely an issue with Apple -- one that they haven't acknowledged.  I hope it's ironed out in the future.  Thanks and G/L!!

Answer (score 3):

Which URL are you using to connect to the Apple servers?

The sandbox url is:

https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

When launching the app or going live the url needs to be changed to the live Apple servers:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Comment: I'm using classes SKProduct, SKPayment, SKPaymentQueue, etc. But not using any URL for purchasing some product. What do you mean in this solution? Where do we need to change URL? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This has got nothing to with the receipts or anything. If it was working in the Sandbox mode, it's gonna get automatically fixed in around 24 hours in the live version, don't worry. The exact same thing happened to us and we could do nothing but wait...

Answer (score 1):

So incase a where in app purchase in your app not working past 48 hrs, kindly visit developer.apple.com to update your tax information. In app purchase won't function until the in app purchase is updated even the app is  live too.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the iTunes account on your device is set to your real account.  If you are are still logged into a test user from when you were testing your IAP stuff, your purchases won't work.