# In-App Purchase still not working almost a week after release

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store, in-app-purchase

During tests, in-app purchasing seemed to work well, but after release it just stopped. Afer I press the 'upgrade' button, it asks for my password and then nothing. Not even an error message.

I've browsed StackOverflow for a while and found these questions:

[In app purchase does not work when live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753162/in-app-purchase-does-not-work-when-live)

[In App Purchase not working after it has been approved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359625/in-app-purchase-not-working-after-it-has-been-approved)

I thought I just needed to wait but there was no one who waited more than 48 hours. For me, it's been 120 hours after the release. So I considered it may be something with my code.

My algorithm is based upon thus Ray Wenderlich's tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Firstly, in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in my app delegate

```
// In app
[myGuideIAP sharedInstance]; //initialize singleton
[[myGuideIAP sharedInstance] tryLoadingProduct]; //my method to load SKProduct
//SKProduct is stored as a @property in the singleton
```

Later, in the  upgrade view controller, I check and if it didn't load the product, execute the `tryloadingProduct` once again.

Singleton is initialized the classic way:

```
+ (myGuideIAP *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static myGuideIAP * sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                      @"com.mkochukov.myguidemind.proupgrade",
                                      nil];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

This is what's inside `tryLoadingProduct` method:

```
- (void)tryLoadingProduct
{
    [[myGuideIAP sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products)
     {
        if (success) {
            if (products.count > 0)
                _mProduct = products[0];

        }
    }];
}
```

When the user tries to purchase, an alert view appears, asking to buy or restore. This is how it's handled

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
        return;
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
         [[myGuideIAP sharedInstance] buyProduct:[myGuideIAP sharedInstance].mProduct];
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [[myGuideIAP sharedInstance]restoreCompletedTransactions];
    }
}
```

And after that when user hits the "Buy" button this is executed:

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an entitlements issue, make sure they are set.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, had the same problem before. My in-app purchase would work with a test account but not in the App Store. Glad you are all good now!