# When are In-App Purchases activated after app has been approved for sale

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I just made my first `IOS` app which has an `IAP` option and today it has been approved by iTunes Store. After I got the email, I had to wait another 4 hours before the app actually has been added to the App Store.

After I search for it and download it on my phone I decided to test the `IAP` option, but it doesn't seem to work. I am using my original Apple ID email and not the one I used for testing.

My question is, if the app has been added to the store, does the IAP has to work ? Or you have to wait awhile ? Just like waiting for the app to be added to the store after it has been approved.

PS: both the app and `IAP` has been approved by Apple and the status of my app is `Ready For Sale`.

edit:

If I run my app now from Xcode I get the following output from my code:

```
About to fetch product
Fetching products
Got response from Apple
Black Edition Theme
Black theme
0.99
Sending the payment request to Apple
Received payment transaction from Apple
Received payment transaction from Apple
Restored
Received payment transaction from Apple
```

It works how it should, but it keeps asking me for my Apple ID password continually and at some point said `Cannot connect to App Store` even if everything was successful, and after I click Retry I get the `Confirm Your In-App Purchase` screen but it also says `Environment: Sandbox`

I'm really confused why the sandbox screen is appearing.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's servers often lag behind directly after updating an app with a new IAP (the product will not be found by the API). Waiting a few hours usually resolves the problem. We've had this with every new IAP we added.

Comment: Not sure why this isn’t marked as correct, this is definitely the case nowadays!

Comment: For us, it's been 17 hours since the app started appearing in search results and the IAPs still doesn't work. Is this usual too?

Answer (score 0):

You say the IAP "doesn't seem to work" ... what do you mean by that? You are charged for it, but you don't get the new content / feature / whatever it is? Or you select Purchase in your app but nothing happens?

It's been a while since I worked with IAP, but back when I did you had to submit at least one IAP component at the time you submitted your app for review. So both were reviewed at the same time.

If that's what you did, the IAP *should* be available immediately - if it's not, yeah... something's wrong.

Comment: I am not charged and my screen is not updated. I just have a loading bar which loads until process is complete, so I am stuck at loading. But it always worked in my testing using sandbox. And yeah it was submitted togheter with the app

Comment: So... you tap a Purchase Button in your app... Do you get a "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" alert that does *not* include "[Environment: Sandbox]"? If so, you tap "Buy" and then your app displays a "loading bar"? If so, does the bar move as if progress is being made?

Comment: I tap Buy and the loading bars appears. Thats it, it remains stuck there. No message whatsoever.

Comment: Hmm... well, I would assume you are *not* displaying the progress bar until you have received confirmation that the purchase was successful... but you say you're not being charged? What happens if you debug your app now?

Comment: I updated my question with results if I run from xcode now

Comment: As far as I can remember, you get the sandbox Environment when you use a Sandbox / Test ID. Make sure you go to Settings -> iTunes & App Store, and sign-out of any account you're logged in as. Then do NOT sign-in. Go to your app, and try to make a purchase. At that point, you should get a sign-in request. If you sign-in with a Test account, you'll be in the Sandbox. If you sign-in with a real account, you should get charged for it.

Comment: I followed your steps, but still same issue, stuck at loading screen, basically,  I don't get any payment update event (.purchased or .restored) to stop this loading screen. Btw, I also tried from my brothers phone, and same issue.

Comment: I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753162/in-app-purchase-does-not-work-when-live So I guess maybe I have to wait for awhile.